# Show data label on error bars

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a bar chart showing rates per lane (trucking) with error bars showing the % variance between 2 (Feb 2018 and Feb 2019).  How do I get the % to show on the error bars, like a data label?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op3Sa.png)

Answer (score 0):

To add labels to a series of bars:

1. Single left click on a bar to select the series.
2. Right click on bar, select Add Data Labels > Add Data Labels. You can also use Add Data Callouts if you want bubble-style labels.

To change the properties of your labels (number format, number of decimal places, etc.):

3. Single left click one of your data labels to select the series of labels
4. Right click the label, select choose "Format Data Labels..."

Comment: I need to add labels to the ERROR bars, not the bars themselves.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I don't know how LOL

Comment: Edit your question and copy/paste a picture in from Snipping Tool or Printscreen.

Comment: I put the image link in my original comment.  I don't know why it's a link rather than the image itself